# Convert Currency to Number in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I try to do any calculations on a cell that is in the NIS (New Israel Shekels) currency format, I get an error 13 type mismatch. With the USD $ everything works fine.

I want to do calculations on a currency formatted cell in VBA.
For example

`Target = Target * -1`

Why would this not work with a currency other than $?

Comment: Use `Value2` instead of `Value`.

Comment: I already tried that. I did MsgBox (Target.Value2 * 2) Didn't help. Got a mismatch type error. I also made a "watch" for Target.Value2 and the value was $400 - so it's not doing what I thought value2 is supposed to do (give the absolute value)

Comment: Is it truly a currency format, or is it text that has a dollar sign?

Comment: truly a currency format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason the variable you are using is `Target.value` instead of just `Target`?

The following worked for me in a currency formmated cell:

```
    Dim Target As Variant

    'Currency Formated Cell
    Set Target = Cells(6, 14)

    Target = Target * 2

    'Printed the calculation
    Cells(7, 14) = Target
```

Comment: Yes, I see that I don't need the value but I must add that I wasn't using a $ currency when I got the mismatch type error. I changed the currency to $ and now I don't get an error AND the value is changing (msgbox also shows -400), BUT the CELL itself is just showing the number in parentheses like this: ($ 400) and not like this: -$ 400. So I need to fix this AND of course, I need this to work on a different currency (Israeli Shekels)

Comment: Stupid me... it was the () that I chose in the format window. Ok, $ works. Now I need to know why it's not working in NIS currency. I updated (edited) my question to match where I'm holding now.

Comment: Oh my... I changed it back to Israel Shekels and now it works! Don't know if it was a bug or what but all is ok. Thanks to you all.